# C#, No overload for method 'ToList' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#

I try to split by `\n` as elements, split each element by , as node properties, then populate a treeNode list

```
        List<TreeNode> views = new List<TreeNode>();

        views = res.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)   // first split, dump garbage :)
                .Select(line => line.Split(','))   // second split, each line 
                .ToList(t => new TreeNode
                {
                    Text = t[0],
                    ToolTipText = t[1]
                }

                );
```

Appears like `ToList()` failed, I used before to populate Dictionaries, Lists, etc.
The error is

> *No overload for method 'ToList' takes 1 arguments*

Any hints?

Comment: `Select(....).ToList()` (that might have been a nice extension method too)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need an extra Select :

```
 List<TreeNode> views =  res  // new List<TreeNode>();    
      .Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)   
      .Select(line => line.Split(','))   // second split, process each line 
      .Select(t => new TreeNode
      {
        Text = t[0],
        ToolTipText = t[1]
      })
      .ToList( );
```